# Difference between a column as User-Defined Type and using Ref to User-Defined Type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following code snippet :

```
CREATE TYPE ModeleRoue (nom VARCHAR2(10) );

CREATE TYPE Roue (numero NUMBER(20), modele REF ModeleRoue, marque
VARCHAR2(50));

CREATE TYPE Roue (numero NUMBER(20), modele ModeleRoue, marque
VARCHAR2(50));
```

What is the difference comparing the two statement when it comes to modele column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TYPE Roue ( modele ModeleRoue );
```

Contains the `ModeleRoue` object within the `Roue` object and, if stored in a table, then both models would be stored in the same row.

```sql
CREATE TYPE Roue ( modele REF ModeleRoue );
```

Contains a reference (pointer) to the `ModeleRoue` object within the `Roue` object but the actual referenced `ModeleRoue` object would be stored in another row (and, since it is a different type, would be in a different table).

Or, from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REF.html#GUID-B7622138-6EB6-4203-B5E7-91CAD52E9DB1):

> `REF` takes as its argument a correlation variable (table alias) associated with a row of an object table or an object view. A `REF` value is returned for the object instance that is bound to the variable or row.